# How can I convert byte[] to InputStream?

Tags: java, byte, inputstream

Is there a way to convert an array of bytes (`byte[]`) to InputStream in Java? I looked at some methods in [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), but I found nothing.