# PARSE JSON (Encode base 64) STRING in Android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

```
**$sql = 'select * from dish_category';
$results =$conn->query($sql);
$spots = array();  //array to parse jason from
while($spot = $results->fetch_assoc()){
     $spots[] = $spot;                                                           
    }

    foreach($spots as $key=>$value){
    $newArrData[$key] =  $spots[$key];
    $newArrData[$key]['Cat_Image'] = base64_encode($spots[$key]['Cat_Image']);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($newArrData);**
```

**Above is the PHP code, it works perfectly fine and return JSON string, now i am confused how to parse image(decode base64) in android?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
 decodedString.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it one by one:

- [Get the JSON response as string in android.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080336/5137352)
- [Parse the JSON and get the base64 string only.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605913/5137352)
- [Convert the base64 string to byte array by decoding it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7360403/5137352)
- [Create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` using the byte array.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9897458/5137352)
- Use the input stream to create a Bitmap: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)`